# lan cable not detected by pc but by hub switch

Tags: windows, networking, router, lan

I have a long LAN cable that connected to my router and my PC. The problem is my PC doesn't detect the cable, in Windows network adapter settings, LAN adapter keeps connect/disconnect. Now if I connect the cable to a TP-Link LAN hub switch then everything will be OK and I can connect PC to switch using another lan cable. 
Why this is happening?

Comment: Which category is the cable and how long is it? Is it untangled and not in outside environment?

Comment: It's cat5 and about 30m. It's untangled and is in outside environment about 1 meter.

Comment: Do you have autonegotiation or is there fixed link speed (10Mb/100Mb/1Gb)? If it's just Cat5, it probably won't handle 1Gb. 100Mb should be fine even with the 1m outside.

Comment: I really don't know how to fix the link speed so everything is on default settings. My router is TP-Link W8901N.

Comment: According to the manual, the supported link speed is just 10Mb or 100Mb with auto-negotiation. So in that case, I'd suggest to enforce 10Mb link speed on the PC side. Trying at least Cat5e cable would be good as well, if you have the option.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll try that